# FOSUserBundle - user entity in redis

Tags: symfony, redis, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a project based on symfony2 and for user management I use FOSUserBundle. Everything works fine, but I've found one inconvenience. When user is logged in FOSUserBundle runs a SELECT query to fetch user entity from database. With huge amount of users this is a lot of queries, which I would like to avoid. Because I also use Redis in my project I would like to store user entity in redis between request. Is it even possible in FOSUserBundle? I think a good alternative would be also store user entity in session and put session in Redis, but still I will have to do something to avoid SELECT query at each request. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could always cache doctrine queries.

Or if you want to change way users are retrieved and stored you could always override their **User Provider**. This would probably be the preferred way.

For example:

```
class MyFOSUserProvider extends FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider
{
    protected function findUser($username)
    {
        // If user is cached in session or wherever
        // Return it here

        // If it isn't, fetch it
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        // Store it in your cache

        // Return it
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds nice, but are you sure that findUser is a method which is fired at each request? If yes, then I have my solution :).

Comment: Yep, as it is called from `loadUserByUsername` method which is part of Symfony [UserProviderInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html)

Comment: You can check if it does easily, just turn on debugger and set breakpoint at it :)